# Parse error in calling header function in php

Tags: php

I have a simple php code

```
header(‘Content-type: application/json’);
header(200 OK WORKED);
$response[‘a’] = ‘test’;
$json_response = json_encode($response);
echo $json_response;
```

When I request this file I am getting a 'parse error in  on line 2

please help

Comment: Be sure to use an editor that was made for programming, i.e. not an editor that will replace quotes like `'` to fancy `‘` ones or automatically capitalize things. If you can't write in an editor made for programming, plain Notepad or Notepad++ would be OK.

Answer (score 4):

You have wrong quotes.

1. Instead of

   ```
   header(‘Content-type: application/json’);
   ```

   use

   ```
   header('Content-type: application/json');
   ```
2. The same is in line:

   ```
   $response[‘a’] = ‘test’;
   ```

   where it should be:

   ```
   $response['a'] = 'test';
   ```
3. I also don't know what is:

   ```
   header(200 OK WORKED);
   ```

   you should probably use quotes here:

   ```
   header('200 OK WORKED');
   ```

   But in fact there is no such status.